# Master template for Mandrill

Tags: mandrill

Could you tell me if this is possible to create some master template in Mandrill or so? For example when I have many email templates where the same footer and header parts I have to copy and paste all html and only main content is different. Could I avoid this somehow by using some master template?

Comment: Great question! Always wondered same myself and have so much copy paste